my ubuntu wine cannot run properly my code
I have wine-9.19 (staging) and I have a code with 2 files .C and a file .h
in this code I need to scan 10 numbers and print theses numbers, but when I compile with my terminal using wine I put "1" and this " 0 0 0 0 0 260713200 31326 -1712664256 32765" appears immediately.
I have another code and it worked properly, so I thought that's the code, but i tried in onlinegdb, and it works, so I really dont know what's going on.
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"
int main (){
    int vetor[10];
    reading(vetor);
    printing(vetor);
    return 0;
}

thats my ordenacao.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"

void reading (int vetor[]){
    printf ("digite 10 numeros\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i-=-1){
        scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
    return;
}

void printing (int vetor[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i-=-1){
        printf ("%d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    return;
}

thats my function.c
void reading(int *vetor);
void printing(int vetor[]);

and thats my function.h

Just out of curiosity, why do you use i-=-1? What do you intend it to do? And why does ++i not serve the same purpose?

How do you build the code? How do you run the program?

You need  scanf(" %d"... with a leading space before the % to ensure white space gets consumed.

@KenY-N Almost all scanf formats skip leading white-space automatically. The %d format is one of them.

Might you be entering some character other than a digit, +, -, or white space? Starting off by typing "l" (the letter, not the digit), for example, could explain this easily.

@gabriel foloni, scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]); deserves to have the return value checked.  Example if (scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]) != 1) { printf("Oops %d\n",  i); exit(-1); }

wine can't compile code -- it is for running windows programs on linux.  What does that have to do with you problem?   There are no windows programs here, so no need for wine.

I solved his problem on the staging ground phase. The op was building the .exe file in linux using visual studio terminal to execute gcc, and due to the filename, there was a misunderstanding if it was a linux or windows app. But I guess it's ok now. The op knows that the app will only run inside linux despite the .exe inside the filename. That's the problem with staging ground imo. I attempted to make the post clearer and accudentally solved it. Now my comments disappeared leading to this confusion.
